# What is the difference between Quartz Scheduler and JMS?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, quartz-scheduler

I would like know what is the difference between the Quartz Scheduler and JMS, and in what situations is better to do the use of the tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quartz scheduler is basically about running tasks in / to a schedule.  For example, "do XYZ at 10 am every Friday".

JMS is about reliable sending, queueing and delivery of messages between different Java programs (clients) potentially running on different machines.

> ... in what situations is better to do the use of the tools.

As you can see they perform mostly unrelated functions.  Use which ever provides the functionality that you actually need ... or both if you need both scheduling and queuing.

Answer (score 7):

They are completely different.  One is an event scheduler, the other is a messaging / queuing technology.

Answer (score 0):

[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is a library/product for scheduling jobs (just as you cronjobs on most UNIX systems). You can find a little turorial and example of using Quartz [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/).

On the other hand:

> The Java Message Service (JMS) API is a Java Message Oriented
>   Middleware (MOM) API [1](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for sending messages between two or more
>   clients

Answer (score 0):

One other difference is that Quartz is a ready-to-use **product**, and JMS is only a **specification** (requires you to select an implementation to use it).